# Why is rails returning a 401 Unauthorized status and why does it say that the user exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-redux

I'm in the process of writing a single page app with rails, react, and redux; and this is what the full error message looks like:

```
Started POST "/api/users" for ::1 at 2020-01-27 21:48:27 -0800
Processing by Api::UsersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"racookin", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "nickname"=>"racookin", "gender"=>"female", "birthday"=>"1990-07-07"}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:6
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["username", "racookin"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:6
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:6
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."session_token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["session_token", "9B3Uo1FGMnJDeASGGucj_Q"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:6
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:6
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 274ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 10.6ms)
```

I'm trying to understand what this is saying so that I can figure out where to even start looking for the bug; it seems that it returns the 401 Unauthorized error, and it's saying that the user exists (even when I try signing up with a new user). What exactly is happening here? Also, is it hitting the database 3 times?

Update: I think I understand that it's failing because the user isn't being saved, which means it's probably failing one of the validations.

Here's what I have on my User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_reader :password 

  validates :username, :email, :nickname, :gender, :birthday, :password_digest, :session_token, presence: true
  validates :username, :email, :session_token, uniqueness: true 
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}, allow_nil: true

  after_initialize :ensure_session_token
...
```

And here's a more detailed look at my schema for the users table:

```
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :bigint           not null, primary key
#  username        :string           not null
#  email           :string           not null
#  nickname        :string           not null
#  gender          :string           not null
#  birthday        :date             not null
#  password_digest :string           not null
#  session_token   :string           not null
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
```

Could one of these validations be failing? I assumed that because the values for these columns are being set in the form, my user would pass the validations; but am I wrong?

UPDATE: I've fixed the email parameter issue, but I still seem to be getting the 401 status error:

```
Started POST "/api/users" for ::1 at 2020-01-28 08:54:20 -0800
Processing by Api::UsersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "nickname"=>"pooh", "gender"=>"male", "birthday"=>"2002-02-02", "email"=>"pooh10"}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:6
  User Exists (1.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["username", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:6
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "pooh10"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:6
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."session_token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["session_token", "232kGIICEzCUSSesxgeYfg"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:6
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:6
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 284ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 12.3ms)
```

Comment: You don't send `:email` parameter, but it is required by your validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your request params for `api/users`.

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"racookin", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "nickname"=>"racookin", "gender"=>"female", "birthday"=>"1990-07-07"}}
```

You are not passing email in your params. And according to your models, you added `uniqueness` validation for email.

```
validates :username, :email, :session_token, uniqueness: true
```

Now when active record trying to validate your record with existing records, it found a record with `null email` so it returned validation failed message to you.

If you want to save record with null values you need to add `:allow_nil => true` in your models for the email field.

## Edit

to set username random in your `users` model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 .....
 .....
 .....
 before_save :assign_username


def assign_username
  return unless self.username.blank?
  self.username = SecureRandom.alphanumeric(8)
end
```

Comment: Hm, so I've added the email parameter, but it still seems to giving me the 401 error, let me update the code above!

Comment: In your updated code you are passing `"username"=>""` and in your models, you added uniqueness validation for username.

Comment: Ahh I see; what would be a good way to workaround that? Is there a way to assign unique strings to usernames when I'm making the initial state of the user?

Comment: I have added a workaround to add a random string as the username.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you are saving a record that is not directly associated with the model.

For instance I was using this;

```
@employee.build_admin_reference(recommendee: current_admin)
```

Where the "current_admin" is an Admin model and the "recommendee" hash parameter passed should be an Employee model. I was passing an Admin rather than the Employee record.

This scenario causes the request to respond a 401 status in rails to protect the request.

I changed that to

```
@employee.build_admin_reference(recommendee: current_admin.adminable)
```

The "adminable" here is a polymorphic association reference to Employee and thus returning an Employee Model. By doing that, it respond with a 200 status.